# CSS: background-attachment: fixed and border-radius

Tags: html, css, firefox, background-image, background-attachment

I have a website with a large background image. Now I want to add circle buttons/links that also have background images.

It renders fine in Chrome and IE, but Firefox shows an ugly box with the same `background-color` that the `<body>` has.

The problem seems to appear as soon as you *combine* `background-attachment: fixed;` on the outer container with `border-radius` on the circle button.

I suppose this is a Firefox bug. Anyone has a workaround for this?

*P.S.: If I run it here via "Run code snippet", it renders correctly in Firefox! Why is that?!*

**Chrome/IE (both circles are correct):**

[image]

**Firefox (second circle, where the pink box has `background-attachment: fixed;`, is broken):**

[image: Firefox]

```css
body {
 background-color: gray;
}
#wrapper1 {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-image: url("http://www.edda-hsu.net/images/ProductImages/Fabrics/BasicFabrics/smooth-velvet-magenta.jpg");
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#wrapper2 {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-image: url("http://www.edda-hsu.net/images/ProductImages/Fabrics/BasicFabrics/smooth-velvet-magenta.jpg");
 background-attachment: fixed;  /* PROBLEM */
}
.box {
 display: block;
 background-image: url("https://d2d00szk9na1qq.cloudfront.net/Product/ac6714d6-578e-42d4-b81f-aaf7a7e5d580/Images/Large_CV-174.jpg");
 background-attachment: fixed;
 border-radius: 50%;   /* PROBLEM */
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>

 <div id="wrapper1">
  <div class="box"></div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="wrapper2">
  <div class="box"></div>
 </div>
 
</body>
```

Comment: It does it in the code snippet if you go to full page. It also do a lot of other crazy stuff while you resize the page.

Comment: Oh, right. In "full page", it even shows the error with the first box - the one that is usually correct even in Firefox. ;) So don't trust this preview.
(Then again, maybe this is something that may point to the solution?)